# How do I edit an ai file using the Illustrator SDK?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have read that there is the Illustrator SDK to edit AI files, but I just don't find it here:

https://developer.adobe.com/console/home

Where is that SDK located?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it:

https://developer.adobe.com/console/servicesandapis

And then one has to click "Downloads", "Adobe Illustrator", "View Downloads".